# fill remaining space with div width auto

Tags: html, css, width

hey guys thanks for the upcoming support how do I set the blue to fill up the remaining width of the whole maininfo div? I tried setting the **width:auto**

```
<div class="maininfo">
    <div class="large">2</div>
    <div class="smallblock">
        <div class="smalltop">3</div>
        <div class="small">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="smallblock">
        <div class="smalltop">5</div>
        <div class="small">6</div>
    </div>
</div>

.maininfo {

    width: 600px;

}

.large {
    float: left;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: blue;
    width:auto;
}


.smallblock {
    float: right;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    width: 20%;
}

.small {
background-color: red;
height: 50%;
width: 100%;
}
.smalltop {
background-color: red;
height: 50%;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

UPDATED MY JFIDDLE BUT NOW IT MAKES 2 LINES: http://jsfiddle.net/4ykf5frk/11/

Comment: I mean **whole**, I apologize and will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just .maininfo, merely add a 'background: blue;' property to your style declaration:

```
    .maininfo {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 600px;
    }
```

Otherwise, just add a 'background: blue;' property for the 'body' element:

```
    body {
      background-color: blue;
    }
```